# Sql BigQuery - Delete Duplicate Row by ignore the null values row

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to delete the duplicate row ID but I want to ignore the null value. This is my data Bill_ID:

[image]

Im using this query to delete the duplication row:

```
select * from (
select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BILL_ID ORDER BY BILL_ID ) rownum
from `tbl.abc` )
where BILL_ID is not null AND rownum = 1;
```

But it deletes the null duplication row also. What I want is just to delete the duplicate values for not null row.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please add sample data to your question which actually has duplicates, before and after, so we may see what your intended logic is here.

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select *
from your_table
where true
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by bill_id) 
or bill_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just put the `WHERE BILL_ID IS NOT NULL` into the sub query instead of on the wrapper select.